# Adding a new Country name to the Country Field of Address by changing an existing Country name

Tags: localisation

I need to add a new Country name to the Field of Country in address by changing an existing Country name, but i can't find the place that the country names Are Stored.

[image: i need new country name]

For example i Need to change the "Tuvala" Option to my desired Country name.

and also i need too change this value in other Localization formats.

how can i do this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model that loads the country information for use in the config is `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Country`

Here it will load all the options from the directory country collection and return them as an options array.

The collection class is `Mage_Directory_Model_Resource_Country_Collection`

```
$this->_options = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadData()->toOptionArray(false);
```

Completely new countries would need to be added in the correct tables.

1. directory_country
2. directory_country_region & directory_country_region_name

There would then need to be a new entry in the Locale Data xml file under /lib/Zend/Locale/Data. After making these changes you will need to clear you cache.

Comment: Hi David. 
i will check

Comment: It worked for me

Comment: Glad it works. Feel free to accept

Comment: @DavidManners will you please answer the question how to update country name in magento2